# Big Commerce thumbnails

Tags: jquery, html, css, bigcommerce

I've recently put together a site fo a client through big commerce. I've changed the code for the theme along with styling through the site settings.

I need to have the thumbnails for products showing up in the main photo box when hovered over, as the theme originally came with the images as a slideshow i tried to change this.

Can anyone help me with this as it's a mountain of code to work it out and it;s not so straight forward to change, any help would be appreciated.

The site is [beegfted.com](http://beegfted.com)

Comment: hire an intern to work on it for u

Comment: It looks like your link does not work. are you sure it is correct?